# PyTest: "no tests ran" even though tests were clearly run

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have the following config file for `pytest`:

```bash
[pytest] 
filterwarnings = 
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
    ignore::UserWarning 

python_files = 
    test_file_1.py 
    test_file_2.py

log_cli = True 
log_level = INFO
```

I run `pytest` locally with the following command:

```py
python -m pytest path
```

and get the output

```
====================================================================================================== no tests ran in 24.77s =======================================================================================================
```

which I cannot believe, since before, I get the following output in the terminal (because of the logging):

```
INFO     root:test_file_1.py:40 torch.Size([100, 71])
```

I noticed that if I remove the `filterwarnings` in `pytest.ini`, I get a `warnings summary`, but not the output "no tests ran".

What exactly is happening here? Why does `filterwarnings` lead to the output "no tests ran"?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the contents of `test_file_1.py` and `test_file_2.py`? Please add those as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pytest` expects test methods to be named a certain way. Eg `def test_1():`.

If you just throw python code into a file and run it with `pytest`:

```py
import time

time.sleep(2)
```

You'll see: `no tests ran in 2.01s`.

But if you have a method that starts with `test_` in your file and run it with `pytest`:

```py
import time

def test_1():
    time.sleep(2)
```

You'll see: `1 passed in 2.01s`.

So it's important to follow the naming conventions set by `pytest` if you want your tests to be discovered. (More info on discovery rules: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

Have your files start with `test_`, and have your methods start with `test_` so that the default `pytest` discovery rules find your tests.